# How to read file from github path using airflow (cloud composer)

Tags: github, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We have one requirement that we need to compare SQL files present in git folder from airflow(we are using GCP cloud composer). I was searching for this solution but everywhere I am getting information about CICD. Can anyone help me here. Thanks in advance.

1. Is this possible to access file from git into airflow dag ?
2. If yes, can you please help me with any link/steps/reference document which will guide me.
   I want to read files from git repo and process them in DAG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

With python, you can access Github repo files via the API, so you GET request with `requets` lib will be enough to read your SQL files:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<user>/<repo>/master/<file>?token=<token>")
sql_txt = response.text()
```

### Option 2

Also you can use the lib [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub):

```py
from github import Github

# using an access token
github_client = Github("<access token>")

## Github Enterprise with custom hostname
## github_client = Github(base_url="https://{hostname}/api/v3", login_or_token="<access token>")

sql_text = (
    github_client
    .get_user("<repo owner>")
    .get_repo("<repo name>")
    .get_contents("<file path>")
    .decoded_content.decode()
)
```

### Airflow

But with airflow, you can store the Github creds in an airflow connection, then use [GithubHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-github/1.0.3/_modules/airflow/providers/github/hooks/github.html#GithubHook) which read the connection and init the github client for you, so you can get this client to read the file as explained in option 2:

```py
from airflow.providers.github.hooks.github import GithubHook

github_hook = GithubHook(github_conn_id="<github conn id>")

github_client = github_hook.client

# read the file ...
```

You can implement this code in a new operator that extends `PythonOperator` if the processing you want to do is simple, and if you have complicated processing you can extend another operator to run your code outside the airflow cluster (ex `KubernetesPodOperator` ).

Comment: Thanks Hussein, i will check these options